# JSON to Ruby on Rails Create Action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json, api, rest

I am using an API for movies, for the most part I use a gem, but in order to get certain information, I have to use `RestClient.get` methods.

```
response = RestClient.get "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/8699/keywords", headers
puts response
```

If I run this code, it returns this JSON "extract"

```
{"id":8699,"keywords":[{"id":917,"name":"journalism"},{"id":4411,"name":"sexism"},{"id":6198,"name":"ladder"},{"id":8531,"name":"panda"},{"id":18290,"name":"1970s"},{"id":18298,"name":"tv show in film"},{"id":41390,"name":"mustache"},{"id":165288,"name":"misogynist"},{"id":167241,"name":"newsroom"},{"id":167250,"name":"teleprompter"},{"id":167252,"name":"what happened to epilogue"},{"id":167254,"name":"gang warfare"},{"id":167256,"name":"multiple cameos"},{"id":179430,"name":"aftercreditsstinger"},{"id":179431,"name":"duringcreditsstinger"},{"id":185281,"name":"news spoof"}]}
```

Now what I need to do is be able to do is turn the above into a rails readable piece of code, so that I can then put it into a database.

More specifically, I would like to take the above information and be able to execute it as such

```
keywords.each do |keyword| 
 Keyword.create(name: keyword.name, tmdbid: keyword.id)
end
```

So that it creates a new Keyword based on each keyword and its name & id based on the JSON File

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `JSON.parse` to turn it into a hash

```
keywords = JSON.parse(response)["keywords"]
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. I ran `response = RestClient.get    "http://api.themoviedb.org/3/movie/8699/keywords", headers` `keywords = JSON.parse(response)["keywords"]`

    `keywords.each do |keyword|`
    `Keyword.create(name: keyword.name, tmdbid: keyword.id) end` 

and get error `NoMethodError: undefined method name for {"id"=>917, "name"=>"journalism"}:Hash`

Comment: ```keywords``` is an array of Hash objects so you'll need to use it like so. keyword["name"] and keyword["id"] should work.

Comment: So, `keywords.each do |keyword| Keyword.create(name: keyword["name"], tmdbid: keyword["id"]) end` ??

Answer (score 0):

It will be faster if you create all keywords at once by first create correct array of values to be saved. Here is what I will do

```
keywords = JSON.parse(response)["keywords"].map do |k|
    { name: k["name"], tmdbid: k["id"] }
end

Keyword.create(keywords) #one SQL statement only
```

Regards